# Reference name of image on JS file with grunt build

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman

I reference an image into JavaScript file, and when I make the build with grunt, the reference of this image doesnt change.

This is the portion of Gruntfile

```
// Put files not handled in other tasks here
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'images/*.*',
                        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                        'bower_components/sass-bootstrap/fonts/*.*',
                        'views/*.*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
```

An this is how call the image:

```
var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            'images/marker.png',
            null,
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(18, 18)
        );
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: regionMap,
            icon: markerImage, //set the markers icon to the MarkerImage
            draggable: true,
        });
```

When I make the build, the URL of the image on JS doesnt change, but the image have other name.
GET 127.0.0.1:3000/images/maker.png 404 (Not Found)

The name of image is
685952.marker.png

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I've had the same issue some time ago and came up with a rather simple solution.

The idea is to use the following in CSS:

```
.map-marker {
    background: url('images/marker.png');
    display: none;
}
```

And create HTML elements with `map-marker` class.
Then, reference them in JS:

```
var markerUrl = /url\((.+)\)/g.exec(document.querySelector('.map-marker').style.background)[1];
var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        markerUrl,
        null,
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(18, 18)
    );
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: regionMap,
        icon: markerImage, //set the markers icon to the MarkerImage
        draggable: true,
    });
```

The URL will be revved correctly.